# the value of constant realtimedata is showing undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js

```js
const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    if (req.url = "/") {
        requests(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Pune&appid=672e1ed0305f6cb61bd4a80a04ef603d`)
            .on('data', function (chunk) {
                let dataobj = JSON.parse(chunk);
                let arrydata = [dataobj];
                // var temprature = dataobj.main.temp;
                **const realtimedata = arrydata.map((val) => {
                    replaceval(homeFile, val)
                });
                 console.log(realtimedata);
                // res.write(realtimedata);**
```

Comment: Please write a problem description. Try not to just dump code and expect us to know what to do.

Comment: Where is the function `replaceval()` defined? How does it work? Is it possible it generates an error preventing the `map()` function to execute properly, hence the `undefined` value for `realtimedata`?

Comment: if I remove the function replaceval()  from map() then also it shows undefined, i checked each and every line but  unable to find the problem

Comment: sorry I forgot to add a description I am using stack overflow for the first time , form next time I will remember it

Comment: @omdwivedi questions can be edited even after they are posted therefore you can add the description even now, if you want; just click on the [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70649691/edit) at the bottom of your question ;)

Comment: Are you sure you are returning something, in your `map()` function?